# magento2 Check Component Dependency

Tags: magento2

I have problem with Check Component Dependency

[image]

How to fix this error? I moved the Internet and nothing helped.

Comment: What does "I moved the internet" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected. There were 2 mistakes.

1 - i have memory limi on .user.ini 756M, i changed it to 4000M
2 - i have problem with session. i did it

```
array ( 
'save' => 'files', 
 'save_path' => '/var/www/magento2/var/session', 
),
```

on /etc/env.php